# Azure: size 0 and encoding error while downloading the file uploaded to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to read file from temp blob using blob uri and write to other blob.
I am able to download and upload file but file size is showing 0 in storage explorer and if i am trying to open/download from explorer getting encoding error.

**My Code**

```
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("AccountName", "Accountkey");

CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(message), storageCredentials);

blob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())

{

blob.DownloadToStream(ms);

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureStorageConnectionString);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("BlobPDF");

CloudBlockBlob targetblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test123.pdf");

targetblob.Properties.ContentType = "application/pdf";  

targetblob.UploadFromStream(ms);

}
```

Comment: Before uploading, just set the position of 'ms' to 0. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to "rewind" your memory: `ms.Position = 0;`
[uploading to azure storage from memorystream returning an empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418053/uploading-to-azure-storage-from-memorystream-returning-an-empty-file)